# Different kind of PlotStyle via Piecewise

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I have a `Piecewise`. For vertical line I have to add `Exclusions -> None`.

```
    a1 = 1; 
    b1 = 2; 
    c1 = 2; 
    L[x_] := (x - a1)/(b1 - a1); 
    R[x_] := (c1 - x)/(c1 - b1); 
    A[x_] = Simplify[Piecewise[{{0, x < a1}, {L[x], a1 <= x <= b1}, {R[x], Inequality[b1, LessEqual, x, Less, c1]}, {0, x >= c1}}, 0]]; 
    p1 = Plot[A[x], {x, a1, c1 + 0.1}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, Exclusions -> None]
```

What are the other options available? Can I make dashed to `*` or `o`.
[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation for DotDashed, Dotted, Dashing, AbsoluteDashing ?

Comment: You can remove `Exclusions->None` and add `ExclusionsStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Dotted], Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[10]]}`

Comment: @yarchik My goal is to replace the all dash with circles.

Comment: You can try `PlotStyle -> {None}, Mesh -> 10, MeshStyle -> Automatic`

Comment: @yarchik I use it. But  this style not work  for `ExclusionsStyle `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  the option `Mesh` with `PlotStyle -> None` (as suggested by yarchik in comments) and post-process `Plot` output to replace mesh `Point`s and the exclusion `Line` with desired markers:

```
Normal[Plot[A[x], {x, a1, c1 + 0.1},
      PlotStyle -> None,
      ExclusionsStyle -> Blue,
      Mesh -> 30,
      MeshStyle -> Blue]] /.
 {Point[x_] :> Inset["○", x], 
  Line[x_] :> (Inset["○", #] & /@ BSplineFunction[x] /@ Rest @ Subdivide[20])}
```

[image]

**Note:** We get the same picture if we replace `PlotStyle -> None` with `MeshShading -> {None, None}`.